# How to delete specific nodes from a custom module?

Tags: 7, nodes, users

I have built a custom nodule that prints a button to a block on the user edit page using panels. Right now it just grabs the userid and spits it out to a drupal message.

My goal is to have the button delete some nodes of a specific content type, that don't have a custom field flagged, that are authored by the user being edited.

I'm kind of lost as to where I even start. I'm assuming I'll have to do a SQL statement

```
function custom_module_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $uid = $form_state['values']['uid'];
    $sql = db_query("SELECT * FROM {node} n WHERE n.uid = $uid && n.type = 'custom_module'" );

while ($n = db_fetch_object($sql)) {

  $nid = $n->nid;
  $title = $n->title;
  node_delete($n->nid);
  print 'Deleted '. $i . ':' . $nid . ':' . $title . '<br />';
  $i++;
}
drupal_set_message('Deleted '. $i .' nodes.');
}
```

However I keep on getting an error saying 'Fatal error: Call to undefined function db_fetch_object()'

Comment: Yes that's very easy. What have you tried and where are you stuck? Seeing your code would be particularly useful

Comment: I have added my attempt in an edit.

Comment: db_fetch_object is a Drupal 6 function. May be your site is Drupal 7?

Comment: Thanks, are you working with Drupal 6?

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that function was not available to Drupal 7. Yes I'm using drupal 7.